# Drag Drop and Save as image in PHP using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mootools

I Have been Searching for Dragging and Dropping Image in a particular DIV and then Saving that Area as an image, But no clue yet so far, I had found something like this. But unable to edit or make something like that. 
Visit : http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/help.minieditor

It will thankful to provide me the Source or help. I want it to be developed in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like [this](http://panyasan.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/open-source-drag-drop-upload-java-applet-for-websites/) or [this](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/drag-and-drop-attachments-onto-messages.html)?  It can be done with [HTML5 and JavaScript](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/), or with Flash or Java, as in the first two examples.

If you are more referring to a drag event that occurs *within* a web application, then that's a different answer altogether.  What'll it be?